# Typescript: How to organize an app

Tags: typescript

Here's something I can't wrap my head around. I have these typescript files:

```
// app.ts
import {SomethingService} from "./something";
new SomethingService().yay();
```

-

```
// something.ts
export class SomethingService {
    yay() {
        alert('yay?');
    }
}
```

-

```
// index.html
<html>
<head>
<script src="require.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I then compile the TS with: `tsc app.ts --module amd --outFile app.js`

However, because of the import statement, app.ts is treated as a module and the actual code is never executed. The alert never pops up. How do I make sure the code in app.ts *is* executed?

Comment: have you tried bootstrap it from typescript instead of html?

Comment: I have, but I get the same error

Comment: you are not importing angular here? 
/// <reference path='libs/angular/angular.d.ts' />

Comment: You're right, I forgot it in the example. It's now added

Comment: you were able to bootstrap your app now?

Comment: No, the line was there in my code, I just forgot it in the example here

Comment: i just took your code and tried in my project but i'm using webpack and it works fine as expected

Comment: So I found it how it can and updated my answer. Please take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here it is you need to tell require.js to handle it.

```
<script data-main="app.js" src="require.js"></script>
```

Comment: How do I import the app.ts file? If I add an export to app.ts and try to import that in main.ts, this file also turns into a module and won't execute - *moduleception*

Comment: [Take a look into this](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/tree/gh-pages/examples/typescript-angular)

Comment: It is still unclear to me... What file are you defining here? app.ts? Where does TodoCtrl come from in this example?

Comment: if you look into _all.ts it imports all the components. and Application.ts has this on the top

/// <reference path='_all.ts' />

Comment: I thought the external module resolution was supposed to replace the /// <reference /> tags?

Comment: the are referencing to the angular.d.ts file in order to you can work with angular in typescript. NOTE:- angular is build with javascript and they added this angular.d.ts to give support so we can work with angularjs in typescript. i hope it helped :-)

Comment: The referencing angular.d.ts I understand, however, in the todomvc project the _all.ts file also references all the project's .ts files, which is something I want to avoid by using the external module resolution instead.

Comment: it's simple just import them as normal modules in you app.ts and inject them to module.
import TodoCtrl from "./todo.controller";
module todos {
    'use strict';

    var todomvc = angular.module('todomvc', [])
            .controller('todoCtrl', TodoCtrl)
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120418/discussion-between-jorawar-singh-and-bart-van-den-burg).

Comment: I have updated the question to a more simple example, I hope that should explain my issue

Comment: ah! so that's the part I was missing. Thank you, it works for me now as well